# Is it possible to do on the fly css/js minification/combination for a firebase hosted website

Tags: bundling-and-minification, firebase-hosting

I know there are heaps of plugins to support minification for nginx, wordpress, etc which run on the fly when users access your site.

I wonder if the same exists for firebase hosted websites. If not it is going to be a bit painful as I would have to minify/combine scripts before uploding my code to the firebase hosted site. Not impossible but would rather avoid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for you to run your code on Firebase's hosting servers. So anything you want done to the source files, you'll have to do before calling `firebase deploy`.

This is not uncommon, and definitely far from impossible. I could recommend that you look into [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/), [browserify](http://browserify.org/) and/or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), but such technology recommendations are off-topic here on StackOverflow. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Frank. Will look into those tools.